# Imagemagick convert -append producing incorrect output

Tags: imagemagick, png

I am trying to stitch together a sequence of images. The first few seem to work fine, but after a couple, bad images appear instead of the specified images. Here are the first several images:

`pieces-0.png`:
[image]
`pieces-1.png`:
[image]
`pieces-2.png`:
[image]
`pieces-3.png`:
[image]

I am running the command:

```
convert pieces-0.png pieces-1.png pieces-2.png pieces-3.png -append pieces-all.png
```

However, `pieces-all.png` looks like this:

[image]

I’m not sure where the grey pieces are coming from, or why the orange and pink pieces are not shown. Several tutorials and the ImageMagick documentation itself indicate that this should work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

First you need to identify the colorspace of your images like this:

```
$ identify -verbose pieces-[0-3].png | grep Colorspace
```

The output would be something like:

```
 Colorspace: Gray
 Colorspace: Gray
 Colorspace: sRGB
 Colorspace: sRGB
```

In your case your the two first one images are using colorspace 'grey', then the Imagemagick sets as a default colorspace on the final conversion.

Finally if you wish to use colors in your the conversion, use the the colorspace of the last two images, final command:

```
$ convert pieces-[0-3].png -colorspace sRGB -append pieces-all.png
```

[image]